Connecting all bones in a chain
I have a chain of bones that I am using for a rigify armature.

I need to have each bone connected to its parent. Is there a fast way of doing so, as individually connecting each bone would be very tedious.

It looks the bone heads and tails already where they would need to be for such, are they already parented together in the right order (the leftmost being the parent of the second left most, which is parent of the third leftmost, Et cetera)?

You can hold down ⎇ Alt while changing a property to propagate the change to the selection.

Switch to Edit mode in the armature
Select all bones
While holding down ⎇ Alt, enable the Connected property in the bone data property tab > relations panel:


